# C++ usefulness of a pointer to non-static method

Tags: c++, design-patterns, idioms

As I understood pointers to non-static methods, they're no more useful than for providing an alias mechanism for a certain method. For example, having an object with three methods

```
 class Provider
 {
 public:
 int A(int in);
 int B(int in);
 int C(int in);
 }
```

and a consumer that requires a pointer to a provider method (be it A, B or C). Having a *controller* that gives a pointer to one of the 3 methods to the so-called consumer, we can write something in the consumer code that uses a Provider instance and the pointer to either A, B or C, depending on what the controller sent.

If this is all that a pointer to a non-static method in C++ can do, is there still a way of providing a more "intelligent" pointer to an object's method, without sending the object along with that method pointer to a consumer? In the affirmative case, what's the idiom/mechanism called (even a way to simulate this qualifies as an answer I'm interested in).

Comment: the most intelligent way IMO is to not use callbacks in C++ but prefer interfaces

Comment: Please note there's a covariance trap when dealing with ancestor/descendant method pointers in C++: you can't assign the latter to the former (unlike it would be with interfaces). See Steve Dewhurst's book on that (if you can grab it somewhere).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your concept of member functions pointers is correct in general.

Member functions pointers are actually very useful with conjunctions to such helpers, as [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), or [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Raw member function pointers are usually ugly.

As for your example,

Your consumer can accept `std::function<return_type(args)>` and you can pass binding of object and its member function to such consumer.

such structs as `std::bind` also allows realization of such concepts as partial specialization and [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a "pointer to member function" is so you can call a named method on any object (of the correct class). So, no, there is no way to "hide" the object reference inside the pointer.

You can always write your own wrappers for stuff like this; that's what the various callback mechanisms for C++ do to give you a more convenient API for the application at hand.

Comment: "write your own wrappers for stuff like this".. what about a singleton manager that exposes a method that has access to one of the singleton's static state variables containing the pointer and the object at a certain point in time? Apart from not being thread-safe, is this one way to overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to glue pointer to object with pointer to method to be called, you can provide pointer to instance any time, ie:

```
class CClass {
public:
    void func(int a) {}
};

///
std::function<void(CClass&, int)> call_func = &CClass::func;

///
CClass cls1;
CClass cls2;
call_func(cls1, 1);
call_func(cls2, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippets, together with the other answer, this provides enough useful information on the callback problem I started from. +1